# Performance comparsion: Algorithm S and Algorithm Z

Tags: algorithm, random, sample

Recently I ran into two sampling algorithms: Algorithm S and Algorithm Z.

Suppose we want to sample `n` items from a data set. Let `N` be the size of the data set.

- When `N` is known, we can use Algorithm S
- When `N` is unknown, we can use Algorithm Z (optimized atop Algorithm R)

Performance of the two algorithms:

- Algorithm S

  - Time complexity: average number of scanned items is `n(N+1)/n+1` (I compute the result, Knuth's book left this as exercises), we can say it `O(N)`
  - Space complexity: `O(1)` or `O(n)(if returning an array)`
- Algorithm Z (I search the web, find the paper [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/vitter.pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esamir/498/vitter.pdf))

  - Time complexity: `O(n(1+log(N/n))`
  - Space complexity: in TAOCP vol2 3.4.2, it mentions Algorithm R's space complexity is `O(n(1+log(N/n)))`, so I suppose Algorithm Z might be the same

---

**My question**

The model for Algorithm Z is: keep calling `next` method on the data set until we reach the end. So for the problem that `N` is known, we can still use Algorithm Z.

Based on the above performance comparison, Algorithm Z has better time complexity than Algorithm S, and worse space complexity.

If space is not a problem, should we use Algorithm Z even when `N` is known?

---

Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand that these algorithms are for data stored on a tape? Are you sure that the conditions under which these algorithms are studied are applicable to you?

Comment: @PaulHankin Hi the practical case I talk is Postgres' sampling, see code https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_5/src/backend/utils/misc/sampling.c#L32 and Postgres' comments.   Plus, if not for tape, what is the algorithm to sample n from N data? Thanks!

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of the hack in the Postgres sampling code described at [Line 89](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_5/src/backend/utils/misc/sampling.c#L89). To me that looks like it was written by someone who believes that floating point numbers are infinitely precise, and you can just do a sequence of divisions and multiplications without losing precision. That's not the case, and the computation referred to in that comment will rapidly exhaust the entropy available from the single generated pseudorandom number.

Comment: I address the question about tape in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [Postgres code mentioned in your comment](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_5/src/backend/utils/misc/sampling.c#L32) actually used in production? In my opinion, it really should be reviewed by someone who has at least some understanding of the problem domain. The problem with random sampling algorithms, and random algorithms in general, is that it is very hard to diagnose biased sampling bugs. Most samples "look random" if you don't look too hard, and biased sampling is only obvious when you do a biased sample of a biased dataset. Or when your biased sample results in a prediction which is catastrophically divergent from reality, which will eventually happen but maybe not when you're doing the code review.

Anyway, by way of trying to answer the questions, both the one actually in the text of this post and the ones added or implied in the comment stream:

1. Properly implemented, Vitter's algorithm Z is much faster than Knuth's algorithm S. If you have a use case in which reservoir sampling is indicated, then you should probably use Vitter, subject to the code testing advice above: Vitter's algorithm is more complicated and it might not be obvious how to validate the implementation.

   I noticed in the Postgres code that it just uses the threshold value of 22 to decide whether to use the more complicated code, based on testing done almost 40 years ago on hardware which you'd be hard pressed to find today. It's possible that 22 is not a bad threshold, but it's just a number pulled out of thin air. At least some attempt should be made to verify or, more likely, correct it.
2. Forty years ago, when those algorithms were developed, large datasets were typically stored on magnetic tape. Magnetic tape is still used today, but applications have changed; I think that you're not likely to find a Postgres installation in which a live database is stored on tape. This matters because the way you get data off a tape drive is radically different from the way you get data from a file server. Or a sharded distributed collection of file servers, which also has its particular needs.

   Data on a reel of tape can only be accessed linearly, although it is possible to skip tape somewhat faster than you can read it. On a file server, data is random access; there may be a slight penalty for jumping around in a file, but there might not. (On the sharded distributed model, it might well be faster then linear reads.) But trying to read out of order on a tape drive might turn an input operation which takes an hour into an operation which takes a week. So it's very important to access the sample in order. Moreover, you really don't want to have to read the tape twice, which would take twice as long.

   One of the other assumptions that was made in those algorithms is that you might not have enough memory to store the entire sample; in 1985, main memory was horribly expensive and databases were already quite large. So a common way to collect a large sample from a huge database was to copy the sampled blocks onto secondary memory, such as another tape drive. But there's a bit of a catch with reservoir sampling: as the sampling algorithm proceeds, some items which were initially inserted in the sample are later replaced with other items. But you can't replace data written on tape, so you need to just keep on appending the newly selected samples. What you do hold in random access memory is a list of locations of the sample; once you've finished selecting the sample, you can sort this list of locations and then use it to read out the final selection in storage order, skipping over the rejected items. That means that the temporary sample storage ends up holding both the final sample, and some number of later rejected items. The O(n(1+log(N/n))) space complexity in Algorithm R refers to precisely this storage, and it's actually a reasonably small multiplier, considering.

   All that is irrelevant if you can just allocate enough random access storage somewhere to hold the entire sample. Or, even better, if you can directly read a data from the database. There could well still be good reasons to read the sample into local storage, but nothing stops you from updating a block of local storage with a different block.

   On the other hand, in many common cases, you don't need to read the data in order to sample it. You can just take a list of items numbers, select a sample from that list of the desired size, and then set about acquiring the sample from the list of selected item numbers. And that presents a rather different problem: how to choose an unbiased sample of size `k` from a set of `K` item indexes.

   There's a fast and simple solution to that (also described by Knuth, unsurprisingly): make an array of all the item numbers (say, the integers from 0 to `K`, and then shuffle the array using the standard Knuth/Fisher-Yates shuffle, with a slight modification: you run the algorithm from front to back (instead of back to front, as it is often presented), and stop after `k` iterations. At that point the first `k` elements in the partially shuffled array are an unbiased sample. (In fact, you don't need the entire vector of `K` indices, as long as `k` is much smaller than `K`. You're only going to touch O(k) of the values, and you can keep the ones you touched in a hash table of size O(k).)

   And there's an even simpler algorithm, again for the case where the sample is small relative to the dataset: just keep one bit for each item in the dataset, which indicates that the item has been selected. Now select `k` items at random, marking the bit vector as you go; if the relevant bit is already marked, then that item is already in the sample; you just ignore that selection and continue with the next random choice. The expected number of ignored sample is very small unless the sample size is a significant fraction of the dataset size.
3. There's one other criterion which weighed on the minds of Vitter and Knuth: you'll normally want to do something with the selected sample. And given the amount of time it takes to read through a tape, you want to be able to start processing each item immediately as it is accepted. That precludes algorithms which include, for example, "sort the selected indices and then read the indicated items. (See above.) For immediate processing to be possible, you must not depend on being able to "deselect" already selected items.

   Fortunately, both the quick algorithms mentioned at the end of point 2 do satisfy this requirement. In both cases, an item once selected will never be later rejected.
4. There is at least one use case for reservoir sampling which is still very much relevant: sampling a datastream which is too voluminous or too high-bandwidth to store. That might be some kind of massive social media feed, or it might be telemetry data from a large sensor array, or whatever. In that case, you might want to reduce the size of the datastream by extracting only a small sample, and reservoir sampling is a good candidate. However, that has nothing to do with the Postgres example.

In summary:

- Yes, you can (and probably should) use Vitter's Algorithm Z in preference to Knuth's Algorithm S, even if you know how big the data set it.
- But there are certainly better algorithms, some of which are outlined above.